# MvvmCross DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

Делаю проект на Xamarin. Столкнулся с проблемой. Я подключил плагин для SQLite баз данных, и получил исключение типа

[image: Выбрасываемое исключение]

Comment: sqlite.dll в папке с приложением имеется?

Comment: А где именно этот файл должен храниться?

Comment: Без понятия. Но приложение его ищет в своей папке. Если у вас его нет - https://www.sqlite.org/download.html